# create key value pair with check box

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got this type of array object:

```
{
  "Brand": [" AWG - ALL WEATHER GEAR", "addidas", "28", "blue", "cyan"],
  "fit": [" AWG - ALL WEATHER GEAR", "addidas", "28", "blue", "cyan"],
  "color": [" AWG - ALL WEATHER GEAR", "addidas", "28", "blue", "cyan"]
}
```

with checkbox category and thier category which come dynmically. 
i want this type array of object

```
"Brand": [" AWG - ALL WEATHER GEAR", "addidas"],
"fit": ["28", "30", "32"],
"color": ["blue", "cyan"]
```

here is check box code in vue.js

```
<input type="checkbox" 
      class="form-check-input" 
      :id="attributefilter.id" 
      :value="filter.id+':'+attributefilter.id" 
      name="attribute_category" 
      v-model="attributeModel" 
      @change="filterbyId(filter.id,attributefilter.id)">
```

here is js

```
methods:{

    filterbyId: function (a,b) {

    if(this.fval.includes(b)){
     this.fval.splice(this.fval.indexOf(this.b), 1)
    } else {
      this.fval.push(b)
    }

    this.result[a] = this.fval;
    this.fstr = JSON.stringify(this.result);

}
```

Comment: How do we know which values in the array is a brand, fit, or color?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a relevant data sample (while technically possible, testing filters with only 1 item is not ideal). As per your method, you shouldn't be using intrusive methods (filters are not supposed to alter data using `splice` or `push`). Instead, you could use `.filter()`

Comment: unclear information, implement it with the snippet tool

Comment: it comes from api .. id "Brand"
filterValues 
0 
id " AWG - ALL WEATHER GEAR"
count 1
meta ""
1 
id "addidas"
count 1
meta ""
2 
id "wrogn"
count 1
meta ""
1 
id "fit"
filterValues 
0 
id "28"
count 1
meta null
1 
id "30"
count 3
meta null
2 
id "32"
count 1
meta null
3 
id "34"
count 1
meta null
2 
id "color"
filterValues 
0 
id "blue"
count 2
meta "#0000FF"
1 
id "cyan"
count 2

Comment: look at  here https://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts  .. filter by attributes like brands, color etc

Answer (score 0):

```
               var farray=["brand:xx","brand:yy","fit:28","fit:34","color:red","color:blue"];

    var obj = farray.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
                    cur=cur.split(':');
                    var key=cur[0];
                    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    { 
                        acc[key]=[];
                        acc[key].push(cur[1]);
                    }else{
                        acc[key].push(cur[1]);
                    }

                    //console.log(acc)
                    //alert(fstr);
                    return acc;
                    }, {});

        fstrobj = JSON.stringify(obj);
        alert(fstrobj)
```